# How to accessing the web pages in ofbiz from browser?

Tags: ofbiz

I create a application in ofbiz.How should i access the web pages in the ofbiz from the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is so basic but [you've already asked for a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395475/suggest-me-a-good-tutorial-of-ofbiz) earlier.
I suggest you start reading the tutorials.

Assuming you've installed ofbiz correctly, run `OFBIZ_HOME/startofbiz.bat` and you're good to go.

Access http://localhost:8080/ecommerce/control/main to see the ecommerce page and https://localhost:8443/catalog/control/main for the admin page

Comment: Thanks for your answer JoseK .Its very usefull to me.

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J: then seriously - read the tutorials - there are good examples of all this.